# is it possible to add multiple editor with ace.js or ace.c9.io

Tags: javascript, html, web, editor, ace-editor

I can't seem to add more than one editor div, so is there any way to add three? However, "ace.js" and "ace.c9.io" only enable one div to be editor div by id, so is there any way to have multiple editor div in a single page?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. Please have a look a step by step suggestion.

First: Specify the **CSS** to decorate or target all (Eg: 3) the editors IDs.

```
*[id^='editor-'] {
      position: relative;
      width: 900%;
      height: 350px;
    }
```

Second: In the **HTML**, somehow loop through (or hardcode) to create your editor's *DIV* (3 for example).

```
<div id="editor-1">
   //JS code block for editor 1
</div>

<div id="editor-2">
   //JS code block for editor 2
</div>

<div id="editor-3">
   //JS code block for editor 3
</div>
```

Third: In the **JS**, loop through or hardcode if you know how many you need in advance

```
var howManyEditor = 3; /* for example */
for (var i = 1; i < howManyEditor; i++) {
    var editor = 'editor-' + i;

    var editor = ace.edit(editor);
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
}
```

Please do remember CSS, HTML & JS should point to each editor - no matter how many you are using on a single please.